# How to move read more

Tags: views, nodes

I have 10 articles in my website and on the bottom of my article there's a read more button. Now, I want the button after the first line of my article, but how I do that? Look at the picture.. I want the button after the text in bold.

Is it possible with views?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use views.

Create a new view for content type Articles, using fields.

Add fields for Title, Image, and any other content you wish to show.

Add field "read more" link, define what you want the link text to be.

Re-arrange fields to render the "read more" link wherever you like.